get element of a QListWidget from clicked button inside QListWidgetItem
I have a QListWidget, which contains many items (in the code named myList).
Each item has a QListWidgetItem which contains a QPushButton and a QLabel.
I need to know the index of the item containing the clicked button in the list, to remove the item using QListWidget.takeItem()
At the moment I have written this code:
    def clicked(self):#this should remove the item containing the clicked button
        sender = self.sender()  
        sender.parent() #this gives me a QWidget object  
        sender.parent().parent()#this gives me another QWidget object  
        sender.parent().parent()#this gives me the QListWidget but I am not able to get the item where button was clicked
    
    ...
    myList = QListWidget(layout)    
    ...
    #this happens within a loop inside a method of the class  

    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
    item_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()  
    line_push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
    line_push_button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
    line_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(testo)
    
    item_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    item_layout.addWidget(line_push_button)
    item_layout.addWidget(line_text)
        
    item_widget.setLayout(item_layout)  
    myList.insertItem(i, item)
    myList.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)


Firstly, keep a reference to the list-widget for easy access: self.myList = QListWidget(layout). Then use indexAt to get the model-index of the clicked button: index = self.myList.indexAt(self.sender().pos()).

I am using a list not a table. However self.myList.indexAt(self.sender().pos()) doesn't work for me. I am trying to do append .row() this way self.myList.indexAt(self.sender().pos()).row() but it always returns 0, regardless of the button clicked

It makes no difference whether you use a list or table: the solution is exactly the same. There was a small mistake in my previous comment. It should of course be self.myList.indexAt(self.sender().parent().pos()), since the button's parent is the actual item-widget.
